# Transpose fixed number of rows in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

I have a dataset(one column , multiple rows) mentioned below. I want to transpose first 5 rows in columns - 1st row, next 5 rows in 2nd row's column and so on. Can anyone help me with SQL query to achieve this

[image]

Comment: This is possible, but it's typically done in client code. It's not the kind of work you want to do on a CPU that typically licenses big money per core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can setup a pivot query making use of `ROW_NUMBER` and the modulus to place the values where you want them:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN (rn - 1) % 5 = 0 THEN col END) AS col1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (rn - 1) % 5 = 1 THEN col END) AS col2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (rn - 1) % 5 = 2 THEN col END) AS col3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (rn - 1) % 5 = 3 THEN col END) AS col4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (rn - 1) % 5 = 4 THEN col END) AS col5
FROM cte
GROUP BY (rn - 1) / 5;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The logic here is that each group (row in your output) increments by one for every 5 steps of the row number sequence.  The particular column into which each value in a group is placed depends on the modulus.